# jquery with javascript conditional statement

Tags: jquery

I have the following [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)  code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.anipic').hover(function(){

        if ($(this).parent().position().left <= 700) {
            $('.bio').css({
                'height': $(this).height()+2,
                left: $(this).parent().width()
            });
        }

        if ($(this).parent().position().left >= 700) {
            $('.bio').css({     
                'height': $(this).height()+2,
                right: $(this).parent().width()
            });
        }

        $(this).css({'background-color':'#55CADF'});

        $(this).siblings('.bio').animate(
            { width: '+=160px' }, 
            { easing: 'swing', complete: function() { $('.biotext').fadeIn(); } }
        );
    //endmouseover
    },

    function() {

        $(this).css({'background-color':'#ffffff'});

        $(this).siblings('.bio').stop().hide().css({'width':'0px'})
        $('.bio').hide();
        $('.biotext').hide();

    })
    //end

//enddocumentready
});
```

You can see the the page here http://afhboston.com/artists_listnew.php

Basically, the conditional statement gets ignored once I hover over the element that's position is less than 700px in it's parent and the element whose position is greater than 700px animates to the right istead of the left. I'm not having any luck figuring out this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try using else instead of two ifs. I suspect that the second condition always becomes true since you are changing the property of what you are inspecting.

```
if ($(this).parent().position().left <= 700){
    $('.bio').css({ 'height':$(this).height()+2,left:$(this).parent().width()});

    }else{

    $('.bio').css({ 'height':$(this).height()+2,right:$(this).parent().width()});
    }
```

Comment: I tried that already.  Still the same results.  The last thumbnail when hovered over only animates to the left BEFORE you hover over the other thumbnails. Once you hover over the thumbnails that are positioned left less than 700 all thumbnails then animate to the right.

Comment: Can you post your markup so we can get a better idea of the problem